# Check if element contains another element with particular tag in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

Xml file has following line:

```
    <Action>
     <Opcode 
        Id="20">"SPEED_L" 0 "#4900" 0 
     </Opcode>
     <Opcode 
        Id="20">"Torque_L" 0 "#4900" 0 
     </Opcode>
    </Action>
```

I want to check if an element "Action" has an element "Opcode" which contains Id = 20 and tag name = "SPEED_L"?

Thanks!

Comment: So what will be the output do you expect after check?

Comment: You can use `Linq` over the parsed `XElement` to get what you want.

Comment: The method can return bool. If this line is not there, I will add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to load your xml and then by using linq you can achieve your boolean result like,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

bool isPresent = doc.Descendants("Action")
                    .Elements("Opcode")
                    .Any(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value == "20" && x.Value.Contains("SPEED_L"));

if (isPresent == false)
{
    //Add new one
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
data.xml

```
<Action>
  <Opcode
     Id="20">
    "SPEED_L" 0 "#4900" 0
  </Opcode>
  <Opcode
     Id="20">
    "Torque_L" 0 "#4900" 0
  </Opcode>
</Action>
```

C# code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
            var test = from element in xdoc.Descendants("Opcode")
                       where  element.Attribute("Id").Value == "20" && element.Value.Contains("SPEED_L") select element;

var result = test.FirstOrDefault();
```